# jQuery - remove one case-sensitive word

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to remove one case sensitive word from the completely loaded page? The word is "Posts" and it's in a javascript generated div called #pd_top_rated_holder.

The javascript is pulled from off site and so I don't have control over it, and I don't want to modify a plugin to serve the js locally.

Tried this with no luck:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#pd_top_rated_holder').text($('#pd_top_rated_holder').text().replace('Posts',''));
</script>
```

Comment: Have you wrapped that code in a `$(document).ready`? Or simply `$()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your code in ready handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#pd_top_rated_holder').text($('#pd_top_rated_holder').text().replace('Posts',''));
  });
</script>
```

If there are more than one instances of the string, you need to use regex to replace them all like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#pd_top_rated_holder').text($('#pd_top_rated_holder').text().replace(/Posts/g,''));
  });
</script>
```

Comment: just one clarifincation , the document.ready function makes sure that it will wait executing till all the scripts are loaded right?? am i right.

Comment: @gov: It fires as soon as DOM (document object model) is parsed and by browser and ready to be manipulated.

Comment: This should work fine with the doc ready wrap, but now I realize that the word "Posts" seems to be part of an image, as it doesn't appear in the actual html source of the page, and as such can't be found and deleted.